# Adding postgresql DB to travis

Tags: java, postgresql, travis-ci

It's my first time using any CI. I have used Travis. In current commit I added `postgresql`, but it is failing building (on my computer (local) it is working correctly) with stacktrace: (whole stacktrace https://travis-ci.org/must1/BookstoreScraper/builds/568424005?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification)

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:112) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$314b4507.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$5(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$314b4507$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ae85cd83.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

I knwo that it cannot find postgres, but I don't know how to add it.

`travis.yml` configuration:

```
language: java

addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "must1"
    token:
      secure: TOKEN # encrypted value of your token

script:
  # the following command line builds the project, runs the tests with coverage and then execute the SonarCloud analysis
  - mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install sonar:sonar
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bookstore_scraper
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults= false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole chapter in the Travis docs how to setup databases.

Especially:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#postgresql

Basically you add Postgres to the services:

```
services:
  - postgresql
```

And create a database:

```
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
```

If you need a specific version of Postgresql:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#using-a-different-postgresql-version

If you need Postgresql 11 - there is a little more work todo (2019-08-07):

Minimal example .travis.yml for Java:

```
dist: xenial
sudo: required
language: java

before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test' -U postgres

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get --yes remove postgresql\*
  - sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-11 postgresql-client-11
  - sudo cp /etc/postgresql/{9.6,11}/main/pg_hba.conf
  - sudo service postgresql restart 11

env:
  global:
    - PGUSER=postgres
    - PGPORT=5432

script:
  - psql -c "SELECT version();"
```

Above example can be amended for other languages - like `language: node_js`

Comment: I updated my answer - Postgres 11 requires a Distribution that supports it (xenial)

Comment: So my configuration should looks like this: https://pastebin.com/zAh59WGm or it should contain something more?

Comment: Looks okay - it is try and error with Travis.... Maybe put `psql -c "SELECT version();"` in the `script:` section first. It should print out the used server version. When it says something with "Postgres 11" - then you are on a good way.

Comment: Here is the build: https://travis-ci.org/must1/BookstoreScraper/builds/568918411 still failing :(  I cannot add psql -c 'select ersion();' as it says Could not parse must1/BookstoreScraper/.travis.yml@e1445dc8b2f569b8

Comment: I updated my answer. Parsing errors are due to wrong formatting of the .yml file. Probably copy+paste errors ...

Comment: Got it, had to add change name of database. Thanks a lot of help\1